# Где найти Chart Control?

Tags: asp.net

Нужен Chart Control (серверный контрол). Вроде бы MS купила Dundas, но его нет в VS 2010 Professional. Есть ли он, как бесплатный и где взять?

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft Chart Controls for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=130f7986-bf49-4fe5-9ca8-910ae6ea442c).